# Branch loci of Ramified covers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\to Y$ be a $d:1$ ramified covering map from a smooth complex projective variety $X$ to a smooth complex projective variety $Y$.

> **Question 1.** What does the smoothness imply on the branch locus in $X$ or its image in $Y$?
>   Does it imply that its a normal crossing?
>
> **Question 2.** If not, assuming $Y=\mathbb{P}^n$, can we always deform $X$ to get a normal-crossing branch locus in $\mathbb{P}^n$ (or at least for its preimage in $X$)?

*Comment 1.* Regarding the nice answer of Tony, you may assume $X$ is simply-connected.

*Comment 2.* By normal crossing, I mean the reduced branch locus to be normal crossing.

Comment: By definition, the branch locus is the locus of critical *values* of $f \colon X \to Y$, hence it is in $Y$. The set of critical points (which is in $X$) is called the *ramification* locus.

Comment: Did you want to add the hypothesis that the $d$-to-$1$ morphism is Galois / normal and has Abelian group of deck transformations?

Comment: Well, I am not sure. The kind of fibrations I am interested in are when $X$ is a smooth Calabi-Yau threefold and $Y$ is $\mathbb{P}^3$. I don't care about the complex structure of $X$, so I am looking for a generic member of its complex moduli space. If there are theorems for those particular type of fibrations, I would appreciate if you recall that.

Answer (score 20):

The branch locus in $Y$ need not be a normal crossings divisor even when $Y$ is a projective space. Suppose $X$ is a smooth complex projective surface with non-abelian fundamental group. By Noether normalization we can find a finite morphsim $f : X \to \mathbb{P}^{2}$. The branch locus $B \subset \mathbb{P}^{2}$ will be a divisor by the Zariski-Nagata purity theorem but this divisor can never be normal crossings. If it was, then the fundamental group $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{P}^{2}-B)$ will be abelian by Fulton's nodal curve theorem. Since $\pi_{1}(X-f^{-1}(B)) \subset \pi_{1}(\mathbb{P}^{2}-B)$ is of finite index, and $\pi_{1}(X-f^{-1}(B))$ surjects onto $\pi_{1}(X)$ e.g. by the Fulton-Lazarsfeld connectedness theorem, it will follow that $\pi_{1}(X)$ is abelian which is a contradiction. In general the only implication of the smoothness will be the purity of branch loci: the branch locus has to be of pure dimension one.

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned a goof set of related theorems. At the very end of your answer, your sentence is incomplete:  " it will follows that $\pi_1(X)$ ?". Actually, I am only interested in the case where $X$ is a simply-connected threefold. What can be said in the simply-connected case.

Answer (score 8):

Even in the simply connected case there is no hope.

Let $X$ be a smooth cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and take a general projection $f\colon X \to \mathbb{P}^2$. Then $f$ is a branched triple cover and it is well known that the branch locus $B \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ is a sextic curve with six ordinary cusps lying on a conic.

There is no way to deform this cover (mantaining $X$ smooth) in order to obtain a branch locus which is normal crossing.

Notice that $X$ is a rational surface, hence $\pi_1(X)=\{1\}$.

Comment: Very nice example. Could please recall one reference for this example. By the way, Fermat cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$, $x_0^3+x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3=0$ via the map $[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]\to [x_1,x_2,x_3]$ is cyclic cover of $\mathbb{P}^2$ ramified along a smooth cubic curve. It is not obvious that the covering you are mentioning is not deformable to this one.

Comment: This is very classical, Zarisky surely knew this. For a modern treatment and other examples, see Miranda's paper *Triple covers in Algebraic Geometry*, section 10.

In your example the schematic branch locus must be counted with multiplicity *two*, since there is total ramification. So it is not reduced, hence not normal crossing. 
It must be a sextic curve in any case.

Comment: In other words, your example is a deformation of the general cover, in which the six-cuspidal sextic degenerates to a smooth cubic *counted twice*.

Comment: That's fine, what I care about is the underlying reduced divisor. I want the reduced branch locus to be normal crossing, otherwise you are absolutely right. May be I should have said that in my question.